# how to match multi parts by regular expression in VBA?

Tags: regex, vba

Take this string as example:

```
:16R:SECM :22H::CRDB//DEBT :35B:IS 123!!! :98A::YD//2021097 :16S:SECM :16R:SECM :98A::POST//2021027 :98A::YD//2021097 :16S:SECM
```

Use the following code, it can only get the first part of this string, and lose the second part. Hope to know the reason.

```
Message = ":16R:SECM :22H::CRDB//DEBT :35B:IS 123!!! :98A::YD//2021097 :16S:SECM :16R:SECM :98A::POST//2021027 :98A::YD//2021097 :16S:SECM"
    Dim mRegExp As RegExp
    Set mRegExp = New RegExp
    count_num = 0
    With mRegExp
        p_string = ":16R:SECM[\s\S]+?:16S:SECM"
        .Pattern = p_string
        Set matchs = .Execute(Message)
        For Each matchpart In matchs
            MsgBox matchpart.Value
            count_num = count_num + 1
        Next
        MsgBox count_num
    End With
```

Comment: You forgot to set `.Global =True`

Comment: Side Note: Your pattern uses `[\s\S]` which means "any white-space character or any non-white-space character" which could be simplified into `.` which is "any character".(`:16R:SECM.+?:16S:SECM`)